# PHP session does not work to go another page after login

Tags: php, session

I want to login in a page. If he is admin, then he will redirect to admin home page & If he is user, will redirect to user home page. but my problem is when I set session to the admin homepage or user homepage, it does not work. there is a code named "homepage.php" That I use to create session in the admin homepage. without this part, after login, user enter to the homepage. But with this part user reditect to the index.php page always. Where is the problem in my code?
   homepage.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["sess_user"]) || $_SESSION['sess_user']!='1')
{
    header("location:../index.php");
} 
else
{
    $username = $_SESSION['sess_user'];
    include ('database.php');
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you put some of the code here? It's difficult to tell you where a problem in your code might be without actually seeing that code.

Comment: in login page you need to set the session, after that you need to initialize session in each page you want to use session.

Comment: I am adding my login code & session code But It does not show here. :(

Comment: this is my session code.
<?php
 
 session_start();
 if(!isset($_SESSION["sess_user"]) || $_SESSION['sess_user']!='1')
 {
  header("location:../index.php");
 } 
 else
 {
  $username = $_SESSION['sess_user'];
  include ('database.php');
 ?>

Comment: Please do not post the code in comments. Edit your question and add the code there.

Comment: @sharvanaz:  Your condition to redirect to index.php includes `$_SESSION['sess_user']!='1'` but I suspect that is probably the id for admin, right?

Comment: nope. there is a column named role. If it is admin, role=1, & if it is user, role=0. Thats why, in checking condition I put $_SESSION['sess_user']!='1'. is this the problem? how to I define "$_SESSION['sess_user']" as admin or user??

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php
@session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['sess_user')
{
  if($_SESSION['sess_users']=='admin')
 {
 header("Location: adminhomepage.php");
 }
 else
 {
 $username = $_SESSION['sess_user'];
 header("Location: userdashboard.php");
 }
}
else
{
header("location:../index.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: I try this. But what if there is more than one admin with various username?? @shobhit99

Comment: Then fetch the Admin Usernames from the database and using loop check if it matches the Input Username